# Request / Respond web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, webmethod

I'm new to web services so I could use a little help.

I have a project that a web service will request data from me and I will respond with a web service giving the data. I've created the response web service as you can see below:

Person.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  

namespace TestWebServices  
{  
    public class Person  
    {  
        public string IdNo { get; set; }  
        public string FirstName { get; set; }  
        public string LastName { get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

[WebMethod]

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Return Applicants")]  
publicPerson[] retApplicants(String idno)  
{    
    string connString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);


    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("selectApplicant", connection);  
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    command.Parameters.Add("@idno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idno;  
    connection.Open();  
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  

    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();  
    Person persReturned;  

    while (reader.Read())  
    {  
        persReturned = new Person();  
        persReturned.IDNO = reader["IdNo"].ToString();  
        persReturned.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();  
        persReturned.LastName= reader["LastName"].ToString();  
        persons.Add(persReturned);  
    }  

    return persons.ToArray();  
}
```

I tested it on my browser by invoking and it works fine.

How can I make it respond to the requested idno from the other web service?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What "other web service" is that?

Comment: It's another external web application that will ask for data based on some parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consume your created Web service. Created one can be added as reference for other project's and through C# code you can consume and get the response. 
Sample Code Snippet.

```
        Service1 webService = new Service1();

        Console.WriteLine(webService.MyFirstWebMethod(“Bradd”, “Pitt”));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

For more details refer http://www.csharptutorial.in/37/csharp-net-how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-csharp-net-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
How can I get the parameter "Bradd" and "Pitt" (in your example) by another web service though, that requests for data?

Comment: You have to consume the Webservice and get the data returned by that. Depends on what kind of data webservice gives you.It can be in Json, XML, Array, string or any other. Suppose your Web service gives string in that case your code will be `string str = webService.MyFirstWebMethod()` . You have to modify the code as per your requirement and Webservice/ WebMethod.

Comment: If I understand correctly the other web application will consume the created my web service based on the criteria they want (in my case the idno) and they will get the XML file as shown above?
Thank you again for the help.